# Multiple Category Dropdown Parent > Child + As per user permission

Tags: ajax, wordpress, permissions, drop-down-menu, categories

I am trying to make a page which will have Parent Category dropdown list at the top so once you select any category it will loads another dropdown list if there is a child category. and as per selection the content (category page) will load without refreshing the page.

I found two codes from wordpress codex as below

```
<li id="categories">
    <h2><?php _e('Posts by Category'); ?></h2>
    <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
    <div>
<?php
$select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&show_count=1&orderby=name&echo=0&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0');
$select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
echo $select;
?>
    <noscript><div><input type="submit" value="View" /></div></noscript>
    </div></form>
</li>
```

AND

```
<li id="categories"><h2><?php _e('Posts by Category'); ?></h2>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
--></script>
</li>
```

Both code works fine and loads page with the selected category. However What exactly I want is initially there will be only one dropdown with the parent category list and when user will select the category than another dropdown with sub category will appear and than once in the sub category if any selected than another will appear.. and so on depend on depth of the category.

I also want to only list those category which the logged in user have permission to access and rest will be hidden.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want to look into AJAX to provide the functionality of the second dropdown appearing.  I recommend jQuery.  As far as the contents of the dropdowns based on user permission, that should be processed on page generation by generating an exclude parameter for your `wp_dropdown_categories` functions.

Comment: Neighter I am talking about ajax nor any permission issue. It is not loading category list even. Thats what I am talking. Anyway, I have solve that issue myself but stuck on other area of it now.

Comment: I don't understand.  You said in your question that "Both code works fine and loads page with the selected category."  I did not gather that it was not working from that.  In the statement "However What exactly I want is initially there will be only one dropdown with the parent category list and when user will select the category than another dropdown with sub category will appear"... In order to do that you need to manipulate the DOM with JS.  You can load all of the categories into an array on page generation, but it would more likely be better to use AJAX.

Comment: Additionally, I gathered that you were talking about user permissions based on the part that says "I also want to only list those category which the logged in user have permission to access and rest will be hidden."...  In order to obtain this goal you need to generate a filter based on your requirements prior to the query, or filter them from the query as you have it.

Comment: Sorry for confusion but what I mean to say is first code is working perfectly but giving list, well obviously and second code creating dropdown selection but no category option inside and that is blank. For user permission what I want to do is if X user have permission to see A and C category than they won't be able to see B category in  the dropdown list.

Comment: Are your categories populated with posts?  You must have a typo in your regex pattern for the first one to give you a list.  `wp_dropdown_categories` returns a select statement.